# heroku cannot select from table (access denied)

Tags: java, heroku, spring-mybatis, cleardb

i am new on `heroku` and recently i built one simple app on spring mvc with java configuration.

so i deployed this app on heroku using github.

i am using `mysql` as database.

my connection looks like this:-

```
 @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException {
        URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));

        String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
        String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-
        01.cleardb.com:3306/heroku_eb3825f7cae7006?reconnect=true";

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }
```

the app is successfully deployed and i can view login page. i connected database to check if all the tables are auto created. all the tables are created so i inserted some values on `user` and `user_role` tables but now when i try to login i cannot login.

the error logs says:-

```
    \ Hibernate: 
:     select
:         user0_.id as id1_1_,
:         user0_.enabled as enabled2_1_,
:         user0_.password as password3_1_,
:         user0_.username as username4_1_ 
:     from
:         lashes.users user0_ 
:     where
:         user0_.username=?
: 2018-01-04 15:19:48 [http-nio-35848-exec-9] WARN :: SQL Error: 1142, SQLState: 42000
: 2018-01-04 15:19:48 [http-nio-35848-exec-9] ERROR:: SELECT command denied to user 'bd427bc263a111'@'ip-10-84-26-33.eu-west-1.compute.internal' for table 'users'
: 2018-01-04 15:19:48 [http-nio-35848-exec-9] ERROR:: An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
:at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
:at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
:at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
:at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
:at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
:at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
:at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
:at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
:at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
:at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
:at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

: Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
:   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
:   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
:   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
:   at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
:   at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
:   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
:   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
:   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
:   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
2018-01-04T15:19:48.984999+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.findByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at com.lashes.services.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:28)
:   at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)

 Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

 Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user 'bd427bc263a111'@'ip-10-84-26-33.eu-west-1.compute.internal' for table 'users'
```

Comment: have you tried using `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` instead of `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url